# class test in an existing project j2ee converted to maven project

Tags: eclipse, maven, jakarta-ee, maven-3, pom.xml

I'm a beginner in Maven and i have to "mavenize" an existing project for a company.

I opened the project in Eclipse and right click on the **project -> Configure -> Convert to Maven Project**.

So after that I didn't get the folders : **src/main/java**,  **src/main/resources**,  **src/test/java**,  **src/test/resources**. I didn't get anything.

I have the m2e plugin and also Maven 3.3.3

I get the lib and Maven Dependency and arrange the **pom.xml** but i didn't have any test folder and any class Test so when running `mvn:test` i get no tests to run.

My question is : I have to create all the classTest manually ? Or Maven is supposed to create them automatically ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert to Maven would normally:

- configure the Maven Compile Plugin according to the JDK version in use by the original project
- configure the `build/sourceDirectory` element (normally to `src`) instead of the standard `src/main/java`
- ignore the `bin` folder used by default by Eclipse (so may see it in the Package Explorer and you can safely delete it)

Some manual steps are required (and suggested):

- move the code to a newly created `src/main/java` folder and remove the build/sourceDirectory customization
- remove the `bin` directory (it will now be `target/classes`)
- Create `src/main/resources` folder and move any required resource (configuration file, etc.) to this folder
- place your test sources under `src/test/java`, which you also need to create
- if not the case, rename any test class to end by the `*Test` or `*TestCase` suffix so that by default the Maven Surefire Plugin will pick them up automatically (if not possible, alternatively you would need to configure it as described via official documentation [here](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html)
- If you don't have any test class yet, of course Maven would never create them automatically, you are responsible of writing your test cases, Maven would only run them.

Comment: good it helped, please if you have any other doubt, let me know so I can improve the answer, otherwise consider accepting it so that this question would not be part of the unanswered questions (more than 35% of questions for maven tag)

Comment: For imprioving :p Can i rename the `src` to `src\main\java` directly ? or in creating a new folder and copying all the packages in `src\main\java` and delete the main folder src ?

Comment: well you cannot rename a folder to a path, you need to create the folders hierarchy: src folder containing a main folder, containing a java folder. Don't forget to change the pom accordingly (remove the sourceDirectory element in the build element, in order to use the default source directory/path value

Comment: I accept this answer and consider it a solution Thanks @A. Di Matteo

Comment: ok i did it ! can i asking u another question plz ? i did what u told me, my project is a dynamic web project and it's not respecting the real architecture of a dynamic web project : example the file "web.xml" is Under folder "web" without the WEB-INF folder.  How can i organise the Web Deployment Assembly to have an adequate file .war generated ?

Comment: in a Maven war project (packaging element of the pom has value war), the web.xml file should be located under src/main/webapp/WEB-INF, if not there, you should create this folder hierarchy as well. The Maven War Plugin by default will pick it up from that folder and will be invoked automatically by Maven if your packaging is war

Comment: Ok @Di Matteo i'll progress and if i have some problems i'll disturb u antoher time thnx :)